# How to Eleminate hidden special character?

Tags: mule, sftp

Connected to SFTP using mule (3.9) requestor, retrieving the CSV File and observed that it had a hidden special character(?) at the starting of the file. Used `byte-array-to-string` and `byte-array-to-object` transformers using encoding as UTF-8, but still observing the issue. How to eliminate this hidden character?

Below is the code I am using

```
<poll doc:name="Poll">
            <fixed-frequency-scheduler frequency="1000" startDelay="10" timeUnit="MINUTES"/>
            <logger message="### SFTP Localization Started ###" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </poll>
            <mulerequester:request resource="sftp://${ftploc.user}:${ftploc.password}@${ftp.host}:22/${ftpcampaignmapping.path}"  doc:name="Mule Requester" timeout="10000"/>
        <object-to-string-transformer encoding="UTF-8" doc:name="Object to String" ignoreBadInput="true"/>
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

[image: Response payload with special character]

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74491650/edit) to show us the code you have written that is not working which you need help with.

Comment: Please use text instead of images for code and logs. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl  : Mule flow: How remove BOM marker from XML file, this helped fix the issue.